# G Suite migration, alias mails lost

Tags: gmail, google-workspace-for-business

I just made my professionnal mails migration to GSuite yesterday
I created an account for me "Julien"

But I did not to create the alias "info" yesterday, I forgot
yesterday, I just created it today

I expected mails since yesterday on "info".
Can I get them back ?

Comment: When you migrate it's told "you can create aliases later" etc, but when you get into it, it's not obvious.

Comment: Related: [How do I setup a catch all email address in Gmail Google Apps that works the same as the old catch-all feature?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/106934/88163)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that it would not possible and that is very likely that the senders got the following error message:

> 550, "5.1.1", The email account that you tried to reach does not exist. Please try double-checking the recipient's email address for typos or unnecessary spaces. For more information, review [this article](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6596).

**References**

[SMTP Error Reference](https://support.google.com/a/answer/3726730?hl=en)